# SimpleDateFormat.parse leads to very different values based on Android version

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have been bashing my head over this for a little while. I made a small sample app to be sure I wasn't seeing things or the values weren't being manipulated at a later point that I was not catching.

The problem is that when I try to parse a String date with a date format, I get two very different results depending on device API level.

```
DateFormat utcFormat;
String utcDate = "2017-01-31 18:58:12.2334924Z";
utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
try{
    conversion.setText(utcFormat.parse(utcDate).toString());
}
catch (ParseException e){
    conversion.setText("exception encountered: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Here are my results:

```
On Android 4.4.2 device: Tue Jan 31 14:37:06 EST 2017
On Android 6.0.1 device: Tue Jan 31 13:58:12 EST 2017
```

As you can see, there is a difference of about 40 minutes based on the exact same input. The device locales are the same (though I have also tried hardcoding a locale to be sure), and the set time on the devices are equal.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Try using "SSS" only and trim your input to millisecond precision. Do you still see different results in this case?

Comment: I just noticed that interpreting "2334924" as count of milliseconds gives a count of minutes near 40 minutes (almost). Maybe Android 6 has changed the interpretation such that the input becomes now correctly interpreted but not found any hint in the official documentation yet (and your code example does really use a wrong pattern and hence a wrong calculation - 14:37:06 EST is wrong!).

Comment: Is there a simple way to trim the milliseconds in this case?

Comment: Maybe `int dot = input.indexOf("."); String trimmed = input.substring(0, dot + 4) + "Z";`

Comment: Your solution above worked! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general problem with the symbol S is: **The precision of `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` is constrained to milliseconds at best.** Higher precisions are not supported. Therefore it does not make sense to specify more than 3 pattern symbols SSS.

Furthermore, I tried to do some research and found this:

The [pattern symbol table of official javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) specifies "S" as "Millisecond". This means, a value of "2334924" behind the dot in your input is literally parsed as absolute count of milliseconds resulting in about 39 minutes. This explains the parsed time of your first example tested on Android v4.4.

However, the published javadoc seems to be slightly outdated in this detail. If you google for the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616/luni/src/main/java/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java) then you will find in line 71:

```
 <tr> <td>{@code S}</td> 
 <td>fractional seconds</td>      
 <td>(Number)</td>      
 <td>978</td> </tr>
```

But fractional seconds cause a quite different interpretation of the text 
"2334924", namely as 233 milliseconds (plus an ignored fraction of higher precision). This explains your second code example on Android v6. I suspect that somewhere between both Android versions, Google had decided to change the behaviour without any documentation. The best what I could find seems to be the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78859) 78859 which might be related to this change in behaviour.

[ICU4J](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which seems to be more and more integrated into newer Android versions also declares the symbol "S" as fractional second.

**Workaround and solution:**

Avoid using more than 3 pattern symbols S. Instead use (ignoring the higher precision part):

```
String input = "2017-01-31 18:58:12.2334924Z";
int dot = input.indexOf("."); 
String trimmed = input.substring(0, dot + 4) + "Z"; // 2017-01-31 18:58:12.233Z
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
java.util.Date d = utcFormat.parse(trimmed);
```